# How to check self-hosted integration runtime status using az cli command?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using below command to get the Self-Hosted Integration Runtime status

```
az datafactory integration-runtime get-status
```

But it returns all the content and I want to check the node status.  How to further filter the only the node status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the json results by using the global *query* parameter. The *query* parameter uses [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) to query the results for the specified filter. If you just want to get the status for a node it would look something like this:

```
az datafactory integration-runtime get-status --factory-name "exampleFactoryName" --name "exampleIntegrationRuntime" --resource-group "exampleResourceGroup" --query "properties.nodes[?nodeName == 'my-node'].status"
```

In this example we are asking to return the *status* attribute of the *nodes* array of the *properties* object where the *nodeName* attribute is equal to 'my-node'. You could specify whatever node name is appropriate and it should return the status. You can do more complicated json result shaping by following some of the examples on the website linked above.

Comment: Thank you. I'm able to get the node status and self-hosted IR status using the filter.